# A little question about a generalized form of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.

Tags: real-analysis

*This question has no special background, it's based on curiosity.*

Be $\,\displaystyle f(x):=\int\limits_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\ln t}+\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^x dt\,$ . $\enspace f(x)\,$ is strictly monotonous decreasing.

Is any approximation formula for $\,f(x)\,$ known that works $\,\,$*for all*$\,$ real numbers $\,x\,$ ?

$\gamma^x\,$ works only for small values around $\,0\,$ and $\,1\,$ .

Comment: The case $x=2$ alone is pretty non-trivial...

Comment: In the $x=2$ case, by enforcing the substitution $t=1-u$ we are left with
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log(1-u)}+\frac{1}{u}\right)^2\,du &=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}G_n u^{n-1}\right)^2\,du\\&=&\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{G_n G_m}{n+m-1}\\&=&\sum_{s=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{k=1}^{s-1}G_k G_{s-k}\end{eqnarray*} $$
where $\left\{G_n\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is the sequence of [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients), having the following integral representation:

Comment: $$ G_n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)^n\left(\pi^2+\log^2 x\right)} $$
and allowing to state:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log(1-u)}+\frac{1}{u}\right)^2\,du =\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\frac{\log\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)-\log\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{(x-y)(\pi^2+\log^2 x)(\pi^2+\log^2 y)}\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : I thank you a lot for your efforts! --- I first thought about a fast converging series for the integral, but when I look at your calculations then even the construction of such a series is associated with considerable difficulties.

Comment: In the $x=2$ case we also have

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(2)=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log t}+\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^2\,dt&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2 e^{-t}\,dt\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $\mathcal{L}(e^{-t})=\frac{1}{s+1}$ and
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)=s,\quad\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x e^{kx}}\right)=\mathbb{1}_{\geq k}(s),\quad\mathcal{L}^{-1}(1)=\delta(s) $$
lead to

Comment: $$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2 &=& s+\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\,\delta(s-n)-2\sum_{n\geq 0}\mathbb{1}_{\geq n}(s)\\&=&2\{s\}-s-2+\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\,\delta(s-n) \end{eqnarray*}$$
where for any $T\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{T}2\{s\}-s-2+\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)\,\delta(s-n)\,ds &=& \lfloor T\rfloor+\{T\}^2-2T-\frac{T^2}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor T\rfloor}(n+1)\\&=&\frac{\lfloor T\rfloor}{2}-2\{T\}+\frac{\{T\}^2}{2}+\{T\}\lfloor T\rfloor+1\\&=&\frac{T-5\{T\}}{2}-\frac{\{T\}^2}{2}+T\{T\}+1.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Of course, the Laplace transformation is interesting, but I still cannot figure out if it's really helpful in the more general case. Anyway, thank you very much for this alternative approach, it makes me think.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : I do not know how to reach you as a moderator directly, so I try it here because: The year of the time specification is wrong. Sometimes $ 14 $ or $ 15 $ instead of $ 17 $. Maybe a moderator can fix that easily?